# How to refresh the canvas after x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, rgraph

I want to refresh my canvas after every x seconds without refreshing the whole page.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var odo = new RGraph.Odometer({
        id: 'cvs',
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        value: <?php echo $windDirDeg; ?>
    }).draw();
 </script>

<body>
 <canvas id="cvs" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: you want clear content in canvas?

Comment: why do you want to use ajax?

Comment: I want refresh my value in every x second @sinhayash

Comment: use timeout function

Comment: @sinhayash any example? :)

Comment: oh sorry use setInterval

Answer (score 0):

To clear the canvas you can use the RGraph API:

```
var ca = document.getElementById('cvs');
RGraph.clear(ca, 'white'); // The colour is optional (the default is transparent)
```

http://www.rgraph.net/docs/api.html

Answer (score -1):

May be this:

`x = 3000ms`

```
setInterval(function(){ 
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
alert("Canvas cleared"); 
}, 
3000);
```

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
setInterval(function(){ 
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
alert("Canvas cleared"); 
}, 
3000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval)

Comment: `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` Is this working fine?

Comment: pass variable c.height. See full example

Comment: <script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
  var odo = new RGraph.Odometer({
            id: 'cvs2',
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            value: <?php echo $windDirDeg; ?>
        }).draw();
        
  var ctx = odo.getContext("2d");
        setInterval(function(){ 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, odo.width, odo.height);
  alert("Canvas cleared"); 
  }, 3000);
 });

    
</script>

Comment: what do you mean? did you try example? it is working fine.. what errors you get?